# How to extend Vtiger 6 inactivity time

Tags: php, vtigercrm

I am using vtiger6, actually I want to extend the login session of users. I have change the below parameter value at below location. See my code

Path: include/webservices/sessionmanager.php change

**$maxwebservicesessionidletime = 1800;**

I have changed it to **$maxwebservicesessionidletime = 86400;**

Its not reflecting in my vtiger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also change in mentioned location:
`vtigercrmDir\libraries\HTTP_Session\Session.php`

Add below lines in `start()` function before `session_start()` call.

```
session_save_path('PATH_TO_SAVE_SESSION_DATA');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3*60*60); // 3 hours
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', FALSE);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', TRUE);
```

For more reference check [this](https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/171525/extending-vtiger-6-inactivity-time/p1)

Comment: I need to set both: $maxwebservicesessionidletime = 86400; and  also above code?

Comment: Yes. Try it.. Set gc_maxlifetime as per your need